# Unicode-math and declaring symbol font

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode-math

I would like to set the math font as Garamond-Math ([here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/garamond-math)) except that greek letters should come from a different font (for an illustration, computer modern in the example below.). But it seems declaring the new font does not work.

How to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareSymbolFont{gs}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{gs}{11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{gs}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{gs}{13}

\begin{document}
\[2a\alpha=\theta\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unicode-math` does many things `\AtBeginDocument`, you can delay your declarations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}

\DeclareSymbolFont{gs}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\newcommand*\RedeclareMathSymbol[4]{%
  \let#1\relax
  \DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RedeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{gs}{11}%
  \RedeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{gs}{12}%
}

\begin{document}
\[2a\alpha=\beta\theta\]
\end{document}
```

[image: mixing fonts]

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work because `unicode-math` sets the font tables at begin document.

You should use the `range` feature instead:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  range=it/{greek,Greek},
]
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[range=\int]


\begin{document}

\[2a\alpha=\theta\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you for this answer. Where can I learn more about the range feature? (E.g., if I wanted to land other groups of symbols in one font or the other.)

Comment: @Alexis The source is the manual of unicode-math