Small slanted blackboard math
I got use to Mathematica typesetting, where imaginary unity has a special symbol:

I would like to use it in my memoir document. I am using LaXeTeX (xelatex). The following is in my preamble:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=TeX Gyre Termes, SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{XITS}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

I am aware of this post. However, by using
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbmsl}{U}{bbm}{m}{sl}

I get

Font shape U/bbm/m/sl' undefined using U/cmr/m/n'


Maybe Mathematica needs a special symbol, but people aren’t computers and can infer from context. I see no reason for introducing an ugly symbol when a plain (italic! i has well served mathematics for three centuries.

The xits version is even uglier than the version that you show but the character is U+2148 and \mitBbbi in unicode-math

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}

$x+\mitBbbi y$

\end{document}

With
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

You get


I would never figure out what that was supposed to mean. (But the version in the question is not much better.)

@cfr you could not figure out what a double struck i means or what mitBbbi means?

Thank you! I value your perception and the first sentence. Probably it's a good time for me to abandon this idea :)

Double struck i.

@yarchik for example MS Office's implementation of opentype math (which is effectively the reference implementation) never (by default) uses this character on output but it uses it on input and in the stored document to distinguish complex i, then it has a document wide setting to typeset this using either a normal upright i or a normal italic i so it's a style choice. but for tex it's more natural to use a command for that kind of choice

@cfr   Mathematica uses double struck italic lowercase for several constants. complex i  exponential e, ...  they had a voice at the table and got them into Unicode...

@DavidCarlisle Hmm. So i is wrong now?

@cfr no U+2148 isn't the only character in Unicode that doesn't make a lot of sense, it's there and you can use it if you want but not using it is certainly not wrong.

I have the same question as  @cfr, what is your opinion? Can you add a small comment to the post.

@yarchik well, there is my opinion and there's my formal position as editor of the mathml spec and of the entity definitions (&ii; in html for example) in mathml and html. These aren't always necessarily in alignment:-)

basically Unicode has a specific character for sqrt(-1) but you don't have to use it, just as you don't have to use U+2044 (fraction slash) for fractions, or U+00B2 (superscript two) rather than ^{2}.  Formally Unicode doesn't say this is for sqrt(-1) it is just DOUBLE-STRUCK ITALIC SMALL I @yarchik

In the website of Wolfram there are the two symbols of immaginary unit

Downloading and installing* the Mathematica 3.0 fonts, you have a command $\ii$ ($\ii=\sqrt{-1}$). It gives previuos image. After there are in the .sty file the commands:
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ee}{\mathord}{letters}{'241}
\let\E=\ee
\let\ExponetialE=\ee


\DeclareMathSymbol{\ii}{\mathord}{letters}{'245} %%%% see below.
\let\I=\ii
\let\ComplexI=\ii


\DeclareMathSymbol{\jj}{\mathord}{letters}{'246}
\let\ComplexJ=\jj

*I not know your LaTeX distribuition.

I thought it is possible directly with unicode-math. Is your solution compatible with xelatex?

@yarchik Naturally: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510139/unicode-math-and-declaring-symbol-font

You might like the version from Garamond Math:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{NewCM10-Book}             % Or your text font of choice
\setmathfont{New Computer Modern Math} % Or your math font of choice
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}[range=\mitBbbi, Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
\[ x + \mitBbbi y \]
\end{document}


I advise you against using an obsolete bitmap font like bbm in your document.  They only work for printing out on paper.  It will come out pixelated in a PDF.

Provided that you have Mathematica installed (which presumably you do), you can use the Mathematica fonts directly in your LaTeX document:
\documentclass{article}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Font Setup %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{
    % Replace this with the correct path for your system.
    Path = /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/14.0/SystemFiles/Fonts/TrueType/,
    Extension = .ttf,
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Serif Font %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Mathematica uses the "Source" fonts for its letters
\setmainfont{SourceSerifPro}[
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont=*-Semibold,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
    BoldItalicFont=*-Semibold,
    BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
]

% Mathematica uses its own font for its symbols. This font *only* contains
% symbols though, so you'll need to use a different font for letters.
\newfontfamily\serifsymfont{Mathematica}[
    UprightFont=*,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
    BoldItalicFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Sans Font %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Letters
\setsansfont{SourceSansPro}[
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]

% Symbols
\newfontfamily\sanssymfont{MathematicaSans}[
    UprightFont=*,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
    BoldItalicFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Mono Font %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Letters
\setmonofont{SourceCodePro}[
    UprightFont=*-Light,
    BoldFont=*-Semibold,
    ItalicFont=*-Light,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
    BoldItalicFont=*-Semibold,
    BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
]

% Symbols
\newfontfamily\monosymfont{MathematicaMono}[
    UprightFont=*,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
    BoldItalicFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Math Setup %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{unicode-math}

% Mathematica maps the math alphabets to weird Private Use Area characters,
% so we need to set up the mappings manually.
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \usv_set:nnn { mmascr } { latin } { "F6B2 }
    \usv_set:nnn { mmascr } { h     } { "F6B9 }
    \usv_set:nnn { mmascr } { Latin } { "F770 }
    \usv_set:nnn { mmascr } { num   } { "F7F0 }

    \usv_set:nnn { mmafrak } { latin } { "F6CC }
    \usv_set:nnn { mmafrak } { h     } { "F6D3 }
    \usv_set:nnn { mmafrak } { Latin } { "F78A }
    \usv_set:nnn { mmafrak } { num   } { "F7E5 }

    \usv_set:nnn { mmabb } { latin } { "F6E6 }
    \usv_set:nnn { mmabb } { h     } { "F6ED }
    \usv_set:nnn { mmabb } { Latin } { "F7A4 }
    \usv_set:nnn { mmabb } { num   } { "F7DB }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Fallback font
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[Path=,Extension=,]

% Define the special symbols
\newcommand{\imaginaryi}{ⅈ}
\newcommand{\imaginaryj}{ⅉ}
\newcommand{\differentiald}{ⅆ}
\newcommand{\exponentiale}{ⅇ}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Math Serif %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\mathserif}{
    \setmathfont{texgyredejavu-math}[Path=,Extension=,]
    % \setmathfont{SourceSerifPro-Regular}[
    %     range={
    %         up,
    %     },
    % ]
    % \setmathfont{SourceSerifPro-Semibold}[
    %     range={
    %         bfup,
    %     },
    % ]
    \setmathfont{SourceSerifPro-Regular}[
        range={
            up,
            it,
        },
        FakeSlant=0.2,
    ]
    \setmathfont{SourceSerifPro-Semibold}[
        range={
            bfup,
            bfit,
        },
        FakeSlant=0.2,
    ]
    \setmathfont{Mathematica}[
        range={
            up/{greek,Greek},
            it/{greek,Greek},
            scr->mmascr,
            cal->mmascr,
            frak->mmafrak,
            bb->mmabb,
        },
    ]
    \setmathfont{Mathematica-Bold}[
        range={
            bfup/{greek,Greek},
            bfit/{greek,Greek},
            bfscr->mmascr,
            bfcal->mmascr,
            bffrak->mmafrak,
        },
    ]
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Math Sans %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\mathsans}{
    \setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular}[Path=,Extension=,]
    \setmathfont{SourceSansPro-Regular}[
        range={
            up,
            it,
        },
    ]
    % \setmathfont{SourceSansPro-Italic}[
    %     range={
    %         it,
    %     },
    % ]
    % \setmathfont{SourceSansPro-Bold}[
    %     range={
    %         bf,
    %     },
    % ]
    \setmathfont{SourceSansPro-BoldItalic}[
        range={
            bfup,
            bfit,
        },
    ]
    \setmathfont{MathematicaSans}[
        range={
            up/{greek,Greek},
            it/{greek,Greek},
            scr->mmascr,
            cal->mmascr,
            frak->mmafrak,
            bb->mmabb,
        },
    ]
    \setmathfont{MathematicaSans-Bold}[
        range={
            bfup/{greek,Greek},
            bfit/{greek,Greek},
            bfscr->mmascr,
            bfcal->mmascr,
            bffrak->mmafrak,
        },
    ]
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Math Mono %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\mathmono}{
    \setmathfont{texgyredejavu-math}[Path=,Extension=,]
    % \setmathfont{SourceCodePro-Light}[
    %     range={
    %         up,
    %     },
    % ]
    \setmathfont{SourceCodePro-Light}[
        range={
            it,
        },
        FakeSlant=0.2,
    ]
    % \setmathfont{SourceCodePro-Semibold}[
    %     range={
    %         bfup,
    %     },
    % ]
    \setmathfont{SourceCodePro-Semibold}[
        range={
            bfup,
            bfit,
        },
        FakeSlant=0.2,
    ]
    \setmathfont{MathematicaMono}[
        range={
            up/{greek,Greek},
            it/{greek,Greek},
            scr->mmascr,
            cal->mmascr,
            frak->mmafrak,
            bb->mmabb,
        },
    ]
    \setmathfont{MathematicaMono-Bold}[
        range={
            bfup/{greek,Greek},
            bfit/{greek,Greek},
            bfscr->mmascr,
            bfcal->mmascr,
            bffrak->mmafrak,
        },
    ]
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Demonstration %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\testsymbols}{\imaginaryi~\imaginaryj~\differentiald~\exponentiale}
\newcommand{\testtext}{Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs. 1234567890}
\newcommand{\testmath}{\int ABC''_{xyz} \,\differentiald x - \frac{\sqrt{0147}^{\,\alpha\beta}_{ij}}{\exponentiale^{\pi\imaginaryi} \times \vec{q}}}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \begingroup\Large
    \hspace*{5.5em}\begin{tabular}{r *{4}{l}}
                                                     &
        Upright                                      &
        \textbf{Bold}                                &
        \textit{Italic}                              &
        \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}                \\

        Serif                                        &
        \serifsymfont                 \testsymbols   &
        \serifsymfont         \textbf{\testsymbols}  &
        \serifsymfont         \textit{\testsymbols}  &
        \serifsymfont \textbf{\textit{\testsymbols}} \\

        \textsf{Sans}                                 &
        \sanssymfont                 \testsymbols     &
        \sanssymfont         \textbf{\testsymbols}    &
        \sanssymfont         \textit{\testsymbols}    &
        \sanssymfont \textbf{\textit{\testsymbols}}   \\

        \texttt{Mono}                                 &
        \monosymfont                 \testsymbols     &
        \monosymfont         \textbf{\testsymbols}    &
        \monosymfont         \textit{\testsymbols}    &
        \monosymfont \textbf{\textit{\testsymbols}}   \\[1ex]
    \end{tabular}
    \endgroup

    \renewcommand{\imaginaryi}{\text{\serifsymfont ⅈ}}
    \renewcommand{\imaginaryj}{\text{\serifsymfont ⅉ}}
    \renewcommand{\differentiald}{\text{\serifsymfont ⅆ}}
    \renewcommand{\exponentiale}{\text{\serifsymfont ⅇ}}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.25}
    \mathserif
    \begin{tabular}{*{6}{p{12em}}}
                                                &
        Upright                                 &
        \textit{Italic}                         &
        $\mathscr{Script}$                      &
        $\mathfrak{Fraktur}$                    &
        $\mathbb{Double\mathord{-}Struck}$      \\

        \hfill Regular Serif                    &
        $\displaystyle      \symup{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle             \testmath  $ &
        $\displaystyle     \symcal{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle    \symfrak{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle      \symbb{\testmath} $ \\

        \hfill \textbf{Bold Serif}              &
        $\displaystyle    \symbfup{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle      \symbf{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle   \symbfcal{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle  \symbffrak{\testmath} $ &
                                              \\
    \end{tabular}

    \mathsans
    \begin{tabular}{*{6}{p{12em}}}
        \hfill \textsf{Regular Sans}            &
        $\displaystyle      \symup{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle             \testmath  $ &
        $\displaystyle     \symcal{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle    \symfrak{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle      \symbb{\testmath} $ \\

        \hfill \textsf{\textbf{Bold Sans}}      &
        $\displaystyle    \symbfup{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle      \symbf{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle   \symbfcal{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle  \symbffrak{\testmath} $ &
                                              \\
    \end{tabular}

    \mathmono
    \begin{tabular}{*{6}{p{12em}}}
        \hfill \texttt{Regular Mono}            &
        $\displaystyle      \symup{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle             \testmath  $ &
        $\displaystyle     \symcal{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle    \symfrak{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle      \symbb{\testmath} $ \\

        \hfill \texttt{\textbf{Bold Mono}}      &
        $\displaystyle    \symbfup{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle      \symbf{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle   \symbfcal{\testmath} $ &
        $\displaystyle  \symbffrak{\testmath} $ &
                                                \\[2em]
    \end{tabular}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \begin{tabular}{p{12em} ll}
                                              &
        Upright                               &
        \textit{Italic}                      \\

        \hfill Regular Serif                  &
        \rmfamily                \testtext    &
        \rmfamily         \textit{\testtext}  \\

        \hfill \textbf{Bold Serif}            &
        \rmfamily         \textbf{\testtext}  &
        \rmfamily \textbf{\textit{\testtext}} \\

        \hfill \textsf{Regular Sans}          &
        \sffamily                \testtext    &
        \sffamily         \textit{\testtext}  \\

        \hfill \textsf{\textbf{Bold Sans}}    &
        \sffamily         \textbf{\testtext}  &
        \sffamily \textbf{\textit{\testtext}} \\

        \hfill \texttt{Regular Mono}          &
        \ttfamily                 \testtext   &
        \ttfamily         \textit{\testtext}  \\

        \hfill \texttt{\textbf{Bold Mono}}    &
        \ttfamily         \textbf{\testtext}  &
        \ttfamily \textbf{\textit{\testtext}} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}

You can see the exact ⅈ that you are looking for in the top-left corner:

The fonts are set up weirdly, so loading them is a little complicated. There are a few symbols oddly missing, but still, I can't think of any other font that provides bold sans fraktur letters—I've had to comment out a few lines since LaTeX can't handle loading this many math fonts at once.
